Why does the enumerate package remove default pre-label spacing in an enumerate environment?
With the enumerate package, specifying an optional argument seems to turn off the default pre-label spacing:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Default pre-label spacing.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item No spacing.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


I originally asked, "Is there an argument that I can pass to the enumerate environment that will reproduce the default spacing?"  However, I knew that this invited the riposte to use enumitem, which indeed came, from unimpeachable source.  That will of course address the question I originally asked, but it does leave an unscratched TeXnical itch, so I hope that I may change the question.
The question that interests me, even if I ignore enumerate and switch to enumitem, is: why does enumerate do this?  I read through the documentation, which says that the actual formation of lists is done by code copied from the original definition:
\begin{macro}{\@enum@}
All the list parameters have now been defined, so call |\list|. This
is taken straight from the original definition of |\enumerate|.
   \begin{macrocode}
\def\@enum@{\list{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}%
           {\usecounter{\@enumctr}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}
   \end{macrocode} 
\end{macro}


Use enumitem instead

@DavidCarlisle, re, for convoluted reasons, I'd prefer not to.  But, even if that is the outcome, then perhaps I can change the question away from preferred packages to, what is it about the code that removes (or doesn't insert) this space, since the actual list formation seems to be copied directly from source2e?

@cfr, re, typo (or "think-o"), thanks!  Of course I meant \documentclass{article}.  I have edited accordingly.

methodological: if you load enumerate, that part of the definition is used whether you use an optional argument or not. so, whether or not it is copied from the kernel's code, it can't explain the difference because all enumerate environments use the redefined definition. so, whatever the difference is, you need to look for it in the conditional part of the code.

@cfr, re, I agree, I couldn't think of what in the earlier definitions might remove or suppress space when an optional argument was provided but not otherwise, and skimming the code didn't enlighten me, so I hoped someone here more familiar with TeX internals could help me out.

enumerate resets the margin because if you use \begin{enumerate}[{a very long label text} i] then there has to be  space for that so it makes sure the value at 7, a very long label text vii fits.  It is very old code (from the 1980s originally) and doesn't have any customisation options. That said it's pretty  short code so you could copy the package to your oen myenumerate.sty and reset the label somewhere.

@DavidCarlisle, re, thanks—but I still don't seem to have managed to ask the question that I meant.  I didn't mean "why?" as in "what's the justification?", but "why?" as in "what bit of the code does it?"  I thought it must be in the list-making code, but that's copied unchanged, so, as @‍cfr points out, it must be prior to the definition of \@enum@.  What part of the code actually resets the spacing, or what code do I need to restore (say, from source2e) that would produce it?

I would use enumitem  see
What's the difference between the enumerate and enumitem packages?
But the bit of enumerate that you are asking about is
  \csname c@\@enumctr\endcsname7
  \expandafter\settowidth
            \csname leftmargin\romannumeral\@enumdepth\endcsname
            {\the\@enLab\hspace{\labelsep}}%

which (for an unnested list where \@enumdepth is 1) sets \leftmargini to the width of the label for the 7th item (7 chosen so that in the case of roman numerals you get the width of vii which is usually the widest "small" number.
Conversely the standard code does not set \leftmargini there but article class sets it globally as the classs is loaded to
\if@twocolumn
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2em}
\else
  \setlength\leftmargini  {2.5em}
\fi

So it's a  fixed 2em which was thought suitable for the first level list items set up by the class, but if you change the label (which is the entire point of the package) that fixed setting may not be suitable, so 30 years ago I thought it a good idea to reset it based on the label style for each list.

Thank you very much for your patience with my shifting question, and for the time you spend here helping people like me understand TeX internals.
